# reading XML file using objective C (iOS 5)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xml-parsing, xcode4.2

I am trying to read an XML file using objective C language and parse it. I am using XCode 4.2 and writing application for iPhone. I have created Viewcontroller .h and .m files. I am using NSXMLParser and xml file is named as "simple.xml". I have downloaded it from w3schools website. I am not using ARC. There are no build errors. 
Below is my code in viewDidLoad method -

```
NSString *filePath;
filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"simple" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"File data is %@",urlString);    
NSString* str= urlString;
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
xmlParser.delegate = self;
[xmlParser parse];
```

Here is the XML content -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food> 
  </breakfast_menu>
```

But when I execute this code the program terminates abruptly. I do not see any exception info in logs. But it has something to do with fileData variable because in XCode the line in which I am using this variable is shown in green color with text "thread 1 stopped executing...". Perhaps the XML is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and I am using ASCII encoding? Earlier I used similar code for parsing XML returned from a web-service and at that time response was encoded in UTF-8. Or maybe I have made some mistake in memory management..allos, release etc? Kindly help me in this.

Also I tried saving the file with "UTF-8" in "TextEdit" but there was no such option available.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? What line does it terminate at?

Comment: It can't be an encoding issue as the XML contains no non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Try this one <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. This should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed encoding part and passed whatever data I read from the xml file directly to the XML parser and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the xmlParser Delegate method like

```
– parserDidStartDocument:
– parserDidEndDocument:
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

When you use alloc,new,copy,retain then you owned the object and you need to release them later you finished with.

```
NSString* str= urlString;
[urlString release];
```

because you have finished with urlstring by assigning to str.

Comment: I have implemented those delegate methods. I am not getting any error or warnings related to parser delagte methods.